# Setting up the root url in IIS7 for asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, .net-4.0

I have a bit of a strange question. I'm building a multi tenant website with Asp.net MVC 2 and running it on IIS7. I'm trying to get my dev environment setup properly for testing but I'm having a weird issue though.

I created the website in IIS and pointed the directory to the location of my source code. I have just the basic HomeController along with an Index view setup. I have a binding in IIS on my website (and setup in my hosts file) for www.mydomain.com (this is so I can test the multi-tenant stuff).

When I run the site and I navigate to www.mydomain.com/home or www.mydomain.com/home/index everything pulls up fine. But navigating to www.mydomain.com gives me the IIS7 logo page. Is there something special I need to configure to get the root url to show me the Home/index page by default?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("home", "",
   new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
```

or this:

```
routes.MapRoute("home", "{action}",
   new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
```

Comment: @Micah Well, I didn't say that's the only thing you need to do, but it's the most important first step, if you don't have a route that matches the URL then it will never be handled by MVC. If you didn't have that route then I'm glad to say I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your application must be running in IIS7's integrated pipeline mode. Otherwise you're going to need that `default.aspx` from the default ASP.NET MVC 1 project template.

Comment: It's setup to use the integrated pipeline, but still isn't working.

Comment: @Micah In that case, maybe you should post your routes in the question. It could help solving the issue.